# groovy - file is empty after write in gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to create a file by using groovy in gradle build file. File is created, but it's empty with the following code.

```
task prepareJaxb {

copy {
    ..
    ..
}
copy {
    ..
    ..
}
copy {
    ..
    ..
}


  new File("${projectDir}/build/generated/META-INF/com/example/jaxb").mkdirs()

  new File("${projectDir}/build/generated/META-INF/com/example/jaxb/jaxb-packages.properties").withWriter('utf-8') { 
     writer -> writer.writeLine "com.example.xml.endpoint=endpoint.xsd\n" 
  }
}
```

I need to create more files, but I am stuck in here. Do I need to flush it or something?

Comment: Well, your Groovy code to write file looks ok, however there is a problem with Gradle one. Usually code placed inside a task is configuration of task and will be executed whenever Gradle evaluates build file, so code that should be executed during task execution has to be placed within 'doLast' or 'doFirst' closures.

Comment: I ran your prepareJaxb task as is (minus the copy closures) and it wrote the file with the line of text as expected. It worked fine as part of build, as well as running the prepareJaxb task directly. You might want to try stripping out your copy closures from this task to see if that resolves your issue. You could always create separate tasks for the copy functionality.